# How do you implement "std::slice::SliceIndex<[]>" for a struct you made in rust

Tags: rust

I made a custom struct in rust and cannot index it in a for loop.

```
fn main() {
    let vec = Dog::breed();

    for x in vec {
        println!("{}", vec[x]);
    }
}

struct Dog {
    fixed: bool,
    age: u8,
}

impl Dog {
    pub fn breed() -> Vec<Dog> {
        let vec = vec![Dog::new(8, true), Dog::new(10, false)];
        vec
    }
    pub fn new(a: u8, b: bool) -> Self {
        Dog {
            fixed: (b),
            age: (a),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Javascript, in Rust `for x in vec` [iterates over values, not indices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-05-control-flow.html#looping-through-a-collection-with-for). This is (indirectly) shown in the error your code gives:

```
error[E0277]: the type `[Dog]` cannot be indexed by `Dog`
 --> src/main.rs:5:24
  |
5 |         println!("{}", vec[x]);
  |                        ^^^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
  |
```

"cannot be indexed by `Dog`" means that `x` is `Dog`, so you would want to use it directly. However, replacing `vec[x]` with `x` gives another error:

```
error[E0277]: `Dog` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
 --> src/main.rs:5:24
  |
5 |         println!("{}", x);
  |                        ^ `Dog` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
  |
  = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `Dog`
  = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
```

The reason is that not any value can be `print`ed - only those who implement the corresponding [formatting trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html#formatting-traits). The simplest way to go, as again hinted by the error, is to use `Debug`, which [can be derived automatically](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-02-example-structs.html?#adding-useful-functionality-with-derived-traits):

```
fn main() {
    let vec = Dog::breed();

    for x in vec {
        // changed formatting specifier
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }
}

// added `derive`
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Dog {
    fixed: bool,
    age: u8,
}

impl Dog {
    pub fn breed() -> Vec<Dog> {
        let vec = vec![Dog::new(8, true), Dog::new(10, false)];
        vec
    }
    pub fn new(a: u8, b: bool) -> Self {
        Dog {
            fixed: (b),
            age: (a),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d103b395b210e426bde278488c0ed394)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you really need to **index** the vec (as it's in your question):

```
let vec = Dog::breed();
vec.iter().enumerate().for_each(|(index,x)|{
    println!("{}: {:?}", index, &x);
});
```

The output will look like this:

```
    0: Dog { fixed: true, age: 8 }
    1: Dog { fixed: false, age: 10 }
```

And, of course, you need to `#[derive(Debug)]` for `struct Dog`.